# How to handle large amounts of data in android

Tags: android, mysql

I am building an app that gets data from the mysql server using json. I implemented lazy loading to handle the out of memory error. For a while the app ran just fine but now I am again getting the out of memory error again. This time only on data and not on images. Is there a way to handle data while keeping the app responsive? The logcat output is as follows -

```
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): Process: com.opaxlabs.salepurchase, PID: 1093
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.opaxlabs.salepurchase.CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(CustomHttpClient.java:150)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.opaxlabs.salepurchase.AllItemsActivity$AsyncData.doInBackground(AllItemsActivity.java:106)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.opaxlabs.salepurchase.AllItemsActivity$AsyncData.doInBackground(AllItemsActivity.java:1)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-12 09:42:50.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     ... 4 more
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The code where the error occurs is as follows -

```
protected Item[] doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String str = null;
            try {
                str = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(arg0[0]);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str);
                item_data = new Item[array.length()];
                selectionId = new int[array.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < item_data.length; i++) {
                    JSONObject jdata = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String path = Constants.THUMBS + jdata.getString("name");
                    int itemid = jdata.getInt("id");
                    String cityid = jdata.getString("city_id");
                    item_data[i] = new Item(itemid, cityid, path,
                            jdata.getString("title"), jdata.getString("price"));
                    selectionId[i] = jdata.getInt("subcategory_id");// change
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // field
                                                                    // name
                                                                    // here
                }

            } catch (JSONException j) {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return item_data;
        }
```

Comment: @P put you code where you got this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this before. Your JSON response is too large to place into a string. There are two possible solutions:

1) Make your requests smaller. This is the route I chose when I ran into this issue with large JSON-RPC responses. In my case it was easy, because I was loading records from a datastore with consecutive IDs. All I needed to do is request `n` records where `id > x` and then keep making the same request until the server returned no data.

2) Use a streaming JSON parser such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html). This is the best -- and possibly the only -- solution if you can't implement (1) above.

Answer (score 1):

```
This should be inside doinbackground
        try 
        {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str_json);
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("user_list");
            if(jsonArray.length()>0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    responseContactList.add(jsonObject);
                }
                adapterContact = new myAdapterContact(ShareEvent.this, responseContactList);    
                return jsonArray.length();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

here the responseContactList is a global class level arraylist of jsonobjects
and this should be in postexecute
@Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result>0)
            {

 listViewContact.setAdapter(adapterContact);
}

below is adapter

private class myAdapterContact extends BaseAdapter 
{
LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<JSONObject> data = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
public myAdapterContact(Activity a, ArrayList<JSONObject> d) {
data=d; 
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(a);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return data.size();
}    
and then in side getview method values should be set as on the textview
holder.contact_name.setText (data.get(position).getString("display_name"));
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it doesn't match the question or address the `OutOfMemoryError`. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's actually running out of memory before even parsing (see StringBuilder reference in stack trace). It's more work but you should look into using a JsonReader for parsing since it can take the input stream without needing to write the contents to a string.

See this tutorial: http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/android-parsing-json-with-jsonreader/